# Nested foreach Loop Execution?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I am having issue with execution of nested foreach loop execution for desired result. Below is the scenario:

Following are result in two arrays

Result1:

```
Array ( [0]=> Array ( [questionID] => 103 [answer] => Female [answer_cnt] => 8 ) 
       [1] => Array ( [questionID] => 103 [answer] => Male [answer_cnt] => 9 )
      )
```

Result2

`Array ( [0] => Male [1] => Female )`

my code using foreach loop is below

```
 foreach($qrs as $qrow)

        {       foreach($d as $q){

                    echo"<br>".$q;                                                              
                  echo $qrow['answer_cnt']."<br>";}
        }
```

it will get output :

```
Male 8

Female8

Male 9

Female9
```

But My Expected output is

```
 Female 8

 Male 9
```

Comment: why would you expect that? It isn't what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to loop on the second. Just use the first one.

```
foreach($qrs as $qrow) {
    echo $qrow['answer'] . ' ' . $qrow['answer_cnt'] . '<br/>';
}
```

Its quite unclear why do you need the second array but if you want to include it (which makes no sense), just include an if.

```
foreach($qrs as $qrow) {
    foreach($d as $q) {
        if($qrow['answer'] == $q) {
            echo $qrow['answer'] . ' ' . $qrow['answer_cnt'] . '<br/>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ghost!plz give ur previous answer that will help me!

Comment: @NikhilMusale what do you mean previous answer? i didn't revise

Comment: @NikhilMusale sure glad it went your way

Answer (score 0):

Your second array is useless. just do:

```
foreach($qrs as $qrow)
    {      
              echo"<br>".$qrow['answer']." ";                                                              
              echo $qrow['answer_cnt']."<br>";}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this...

```
 foreach($qrs as $qrow)
        {   
            foreach($d as $q)
            {
                if(in_array($q, $qrow))
                {
                    echo"<br>".$q;                                                              
                    echo $qrow['answer_cnt']."<br>";    
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array(
    array( 'questionID' => 103, 'answer' => 'Female',  'answer_cnt' => 8),
    array( 'questionID' => 103, 'answer' => 'Male',  'answer_cnt' => 9)
);

if(count($arr) > 0) {
    foreach($arr as $val) {
        echo "$val[answer] $val[answer_cnt] <br />";
    }
}
```

you can also try this one.